# Deploying Django with apache using wsgi.py

Tags: php, python, django, apache, debian

I'm trying to deploy a Django project on a linode server that has apache, some other django projects and a php project on it. Also my project is in a virualenv and the other django projects aren't.

My Django project apache file is

```
WSGIPythonPath /home/nccylli/www/ylli_transactions:/root/Envs/ylli-transactions/lib/python2.6/site-packages
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/apache2/wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/nccylli/www/ylli_transactions/ylli_transactions/wsgi.py
DocumentRoot /home/nccylli/www/ylli_transactions/static


<Directory /home/nccylli/www/ylli_transactions>
<Files wsgi.py>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>

Alias  /static /home/nccylli/www/ylli_transactions/static
Alias  /media /home/nccylli/www/ylli_transactions/media

ErrorLog /home/nccylli/www/ylli_transactions/logs/error.log
CustomLog /home/nccylli/www/ylli_transactions/logs/access.log combined

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName my-domain.com
   ServerAlias www.my-domain.com
   ServerAdmin my-email


</VirtualHost>
```

The PHP project apache file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName php-prject-domain
    ServerAlias www.php-prject-domain
        DocumentRoot /home/nccylli/www/php-prject/

    CustomLog     /var/log/apache2/php-prject-access.log combined
    ErrorLog      /var/log/apache2/php-prject-error.log

        <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
                AssignUserId nccylli nccylli
        </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I'm running into two errors
in the django project error log

```
(13)Permission denied: access to / denied
(13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=9780, process='', application='my-domain.com|'): Call to fopen() failed for '/home/nccylli/www/ylli_transactions/ylli_transactions/wsgi.py'.
```

and in the php project error log

```
mod_wsgi (pid=26782): Target WSGI script '/home/nccylli/www/ylli_transactions/ylli_transactions/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=26782): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/nccylli/www/ylli_transactions/ylli_transactions/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nccylli/www/ylli_transactions/ylli_transactions/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named wsgi
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try using following code:

```
<Directory /home/nccylli/www/ylli_transactions/ylli_transactions>
<Files wsgi.py>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: @dado_eyad have you added `WSGIPythonPath`,`WSGISocketPrefix` and `WSGIScriptAlias` correctly?

Comment: Can you show me value of each of these: `WSGIPythonPath`, `WSGISocketPrefix`, `WSGIScriptAlias` and absolute path to `wsgi.py`?

Comment: They are up there in the first file in my post.
It's okay though, we moved to another server and configured everything with ngix and virtualenvs.