# Django wsgi.py + Apache can't deploy, but

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

**Environment and version: Windows 8-64bit, Wamp Apache 2.4.9, Python 3.4.2, Django 1.8**

[Deploying Django with apache using wsgi.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427718/deploying-django-with-apache-using-wsgi-py)

followed following post got mod_wsgi setup

```
WSGIScriptAlias /mysite/mysite/wsgi "C:/wamp/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/wamp/www/mysite/mysite/"

<Directory "C:/wamp/www/mysite/mysite/">
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Directory:

wamp 
 |
  www
   |
    testweb1
    manage.py
        |
      testweb1 - settings.py
               - urls.py
               - wsgi.py

Inside wsgi.py(original code):

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testweb1.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The problem is when starting Wamp Apache server, the icon appear green. 
**Server Online**

But when I enter my ip address and port, for example **125.138.0.1:8080**

The page only gives me this:

**Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) mod_wsgi/4.4.2 Python/3.4.2 PHP/5.5.12 Server at 125.138.0.1 Port 8080**

I had done so many research and followed the doc from 
https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango

tried many ways in wsgi.py  , still couldn't get let Apache the deploy Django site from home IP address

By the way, in Apache httpd.conf

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Also tried 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

```
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "{{ project_name }}.settings"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WSGIScriptAlias setting is wrong. The first argument should be the path you want your application served at, which is usually the root. So:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/wamp/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py"
```